# Unable to access external drives

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, usb-drive

I am no longer able to access external drives on my computer (running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). It was working fine a few weeks ago, so I'm not sure what changed.

I get this error message when trying to open the drive in Nautilus, for both USB drives and my extra hard drive:

```
Unable to access "8.1 GB Volume"
Not authorized to perform action
```

When I run Nautilus as root, it doesn't even show the drives. I was able to run `sudo gnome-disks` and interact with the drives that way. If I just run `gnome-disks`, then I don't have permissions and get the same error message.

I don't have this issue on another Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine with the same USB drive. Nautilus without root works fine. So I don't think the issue is with the drives but rather is with the computer.

Comment: Please show us, `findmnt | grep media` and `getfactl /media/$USER`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. My user account was part of the `chrome-remote-desktop` group. Once I removed it from that group and restarted my computer, auto-mounting and accessing the drives works as expected.

I had added my user to the `chrome-remote-desktop` following this post: https://superuser.com/a/850359/588342. After doing so, chrome-remote-desktop auto-runs on startup. Instead of that, I just added a command to run it in "Startup Applications Preferences": `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start`

Comment: Hello, what is your solution? Keep using remote-desktop and auto mount at the same time. I mean once you add your user back to that group `chrome-remote-desktop` auto mount is not working, but when you remove the user from that group, remote-desktop is not working.

Comment: I removed my user from the group `chrome-remote-desktop` and added chrome-remote-desktop to the startup applications via the GUI. Both auto mount and chrome-remote-desktop are working for me now.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use command:

```
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername /media/yourusername/path_to_mounted_volume
```

In nautilus user mode the volumes are mounted in `/media/yourusername/`

Replace yourusername with your user name and path_to_mounted_volume with path from command:

```
ls -l /media/yourusername/
```

Comment: `ls -l /media/yourusername/` returns `total 0`. There's no path_to_mounted_volume.

Comment: First mount the volume using nautilus. The output should be somehow: drwxr-xr-x  11 root    root    4096 júl    7 18:06 disk2

Comment: The d in drwxr-xr-x stands for directory. Of course your name will be different.

Comment: Change yourusername to your user name.

Comment: Trying to mount using Nautilus gives me the same error:
```Unable to access location
Not authorized to perform operation```

Comment: Use command sudo mkdir /media/disk2     and sudo mount /dev/sdbX /media/disk2  where replace sdbX with the disk from command lsblk.

Comment: Then sudo chown yourusername: yourusername /media/disk2/

Comment: The first mount command worked, and after doing so the drive is accessible via nautilus (until it's unplugged). The `sudo chown username:username /media/disk2/` gives me `chown: changing ownership of '/media/usb_drive/': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Can you create a directory on the drive with sudo mkdir /media/disk2/my_dir  ?

Comment: Does the root have access to usb drive?

Comment: Yeah, creating a directory worked but only as root. I also can create directories as root in nautilus but not without root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101477/discussion-between-catanasian-and-kukulo).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it but still can't work.
The workaround is keep username in chrome-remote-desktop.
Remove `chrome-remote-desktop` service from `systemctl`.

```
sudo systemctl disable chrome-remote-desktop
```

Then add command  `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start` to "Startup Applications Preferences" via the GUI.

Comment: `# systemctl disable chrome-remote-desktopchrome-remote-desktop.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable chrome-remote-desktop`

Comment: Didn't work after `systemctl disable` and run on startup.  Still get "Not authorized...." even after reboot.

Comment: Worked after `# gpasswd -d myusername chrome-remote-desktop` so I'm not sure why you said "keep username in `chrome-remote-desktop`" when a prior answer said to delete it from `chrome-remote-desktop` and gave the other commands you gave.  ie:  The prior answer gave the correct solution at least for me but apparently did more than you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue with my external 500gb hdd, I did next, it helped me:

```
sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop
```